Firefox "Save to PDF" function does not print headers/footers
Firefox 125.0.2 does not print anything in the headers and footers when I try to save a webpage using the "Save to PDF" function.
For example, I configure the "Page Setup" to only show the URL on the top left,

then go to "Print...", choose "Save to PDF", and tick "Print headers and footers". The headers/footers in the previewed page are empty.
Similarly, if I go to about:config and change the print.printer_* settings before printing, the headers/footers are also empty:

What am I doing wrong?  (I prefer to use "Save to PDF" rather than "Microsoft Print to PDF" because the latter will sometimes save the webpage text as pictures and not as OCR text.)

It doesn't matter what webpage I print, the problem remains.  In the last figure of my post, the url shown was https://xavierbourretsicotte.github.io/Kernel_feature_map.html

the CSS contains:  @media print {div.cell.jupyter-soft-selected {border-color: transparent;}

Thanks, it works now

@Gantendo, that could be expanded to an answer, so it could be accepted to help others with such an issue.
